# Two queries where the second is depended to the first one

Tags: javascript, cordova, asynchronous, transactions

I'm trying to display a list of items in a Phonegap (Cordova) app, where each item needs an additional query.

For sake of simplicity, I will explain it with an example. Let's say that a `student` can have multiple `course`s and a `course` can have many `student`s (many-to-many) and I want to display a list showing which courses the students are registered to. Like this:

- Student1: course1, course2
- Student2: course1, course3, course 5
- Student3: course2
- ...

First, I need a query to iterate through all the students and then for each student I need to query the DB to know to which courses the student is registered to:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT `student`.`id`, `student`.`name` ' +
            'FROM `student`',
            [],
            function(tx, resultSet) {
                for(var i = 0; i < resultSet.rows.length; i++) {
                    tx.executeSql('SELECT `course`.`name` ' +
                            'FROM `student_has_course` ' +
                            'INNER JOIN `student` ON `student_has_course`.`student_id` = `student`.`id` ' +
                            'INNER JOIN `course` ON `student_has_course`.`course_id` = `course`.`id` ' +
                            'WHERE `student`.`id` = ?'
                            [resultSet.rows.item(i).id],
                            function(tx2, resultSet2) {
                                // TODO
                            });
                }
            });
}, function(err) {
    showError('Error getting students from the DB (' + err.message + ')');
}, function() {
    alert('success!');
});
```

Now, the problem is that in the second callback function (where the "TODO" is), I have no reference to any data of the previous query. For example, if I try to `alert(i)` it will alert 76, which is equivalent to `resultSet.rows.length`. This is obviously because both the two callback functions are asynchronous. How could I overcome this problem and print the list as shown above?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by attaching attributes to the callback function itself as follows:

```
cb = function cbfunc() {
     doStuffWith(cbfunc.data)
}
cb.data = ... // whatever
tx.executeSQL(..., cb)
```

Still, I would think twice if I can avoid the second callback by producing the expected results with a single query. In this case:

```
select student.id, student.name, course.name from student
    inner join student_has_course on student.id = student_has_course.student_id
    inner join course on student_has_course.course_id = course.id
        order by student.id;
```

and in the loop, compare the student.id with the one from the previous iteration to know when to print a newline and the new student name, to obtain to your desired output format.

Comment: Thank you, @jop. This is just a workaround though, I'm looking for a general solution that would work in any situation

Comment: I see. I've edited it to provide a more general solution even if for this particular example a single SQL still looks better.